# Does Samsung Galaxy Ace store location metadata?

Tags: camera, samsung-galaxy-ace

Can the Galaxy Ace (the first model) camera store the location data of where photos are taken? I have been told that it isn't sophisticated enough. Is that true?

Also, does Kik Messenger remove location data on the pics?

Comment: One queation at a time please :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this blog post](http://eurodroid.com/2011/03/10/samsung-galaxy-ace-review-video-and-camera-samples/), the Galaxy Ace has geo-tagging support. So YES, it should be able to store location metadata, if you enable it.

And according to [another blog post](http://www.wpcentral.com/privacy-whatsapp-windows-phone-tags-your-geolocation), Kik Messenger removes metadata.